# Regex match group to string in PowerShell

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, grouping

I have a regex that does a search on a string and creates two match groups:

```
    if ($BASICEDITMESSAGECONTENT -match '(?sm)(^.*?</title>)(.*)')
    {
        if ($matches.Count -ge 3)
        {
            $BASICEDITMESSAGECONTENT = "$matches[1]$SCRIPTREFERENCE$matches[2]"
            echo $BASICEDITMESSAGECONTENT
            ...
        }
    }
```

When I echo it back, I get the following output:

```
System.Collections.Hashtable[1]<MYSCRIPTREFERENCE>System.Collections.Hashtable[2]
```

I don't want `System.Collections.Hashtable` values like this in the string, I just want the actual value string of the matching text from that regex grouping. How can I make it happen?

For example, when I use `echo $matches[1]`, it displays the actual value of the regular expression group, not `System.Collections.Hashtable[1]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [sub-expressions](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html) to index the hashtables:

```
$BASICEDITMESSAGECONTENT = "$($matches[1])$SCRIPTREFERENCE$($matches[2])"
```

Notice the `$(...)` around each index.  All parts of string literals that you want evaluated as expressions need to be placed inside `$(...)`.  Otherwise, PowerShell will only expand the variable names and treat other stuff like `[1]` as just normal text.

Comment: Worked, thank you, will need to wait a few minutes to mark as accepted. So basically, in simple terms, it was returning the type of `$matches` and then appending the `[1]` text to it, because it did not know to evaluate the hash at that index and return back the actual value. Thanks, this helps a lot.